# In Eclipse, can I organze my workspace projects into top-level folders?

Tags: eclipse

My current Project Explorer has:

- Project A
- Project B
- Project C

What I'd prefer is to create e.g.

- Folder 1

  - Project A
  - Project B
- Folder 2

  - Project C

And have those folders be the same as what you'd see in the file system, browsing my ./workspace directory.

Is this possible?

Hopefully yes and I'm just asking a silly question.  : )

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you only need to use the view's local menu (the little triangle) and set the top-level elements to Working Sets.  Then you can assign projects to any number of working sets you decide and they'll appear in the manner of "Folder 1" and "Folder 2" from your example.  You'll also find other uses for Working Sets throughout the UI.